# getline() isn't writing to variable it's supposed to

Tags: deserialization, getline

I am trying to deserialize using getline(), but the variable temp is always empty during debug, while it shouldn't be.

```
void deserialize(vector <Originalsignal> &arrayS) {
    string temp;
    vector <double> vtemp{};
    fstream signaldata;

    signaldata.open("signal.txt", ios::in);
    signaldata.seekg(0);
    for (auto signals : arrayS) {
        getline(signaldata, temp, ';');
        signals.setsignalname(temp);
        signaldata.ignore();

        getline(signaldata, temp, ';');
        signals.setsignalsize(stoi(temp));
        signaldata.ignore();

        for (int i = 0; i < signals.getsignalsize(); i++) {
            getline(signaldata, temp, ';');
            vtemp.push_back(stod(temp));
            signaldata.ignore();
        } 
        signals.setsignal(vtemp); 
        vtemp.clear();
    }
```

it's reading from a file that looks like this:

```
Storm;3;4;5;6;
River;2;7;8;
bouncer;15.2;
checker;2;0;
```

but temp's value always remains a "" until the compiler tries to convert this empty string into an int and then obviously crashes. I don't know whether the problem is with the file or with getline().

Comment: *a file that looks like this*  What's actually in that file?  From the code you posted, it looks likes you're expecting it to be ASCII characters.  It may not be - it may be in some other encoding.  Can you do a hex dump of the file contents?

Comment: @AndrewHenle . the actual contents of the file are actually what i wrote in the post. the file is generated by another function that uses ofstream and << operator. i am not sure of the encoding that is used, but the hex view of the file is this:

53 74 6f 72 6d 3b 33 3b 34 3b 35 3b 36 3b 0d 0a
52 69 76 65 72 3b 32 3b 37 3b 38 3b 0d 0a 62 6f
75 6e 63 65 72 3b 31 35 2e 32 3b 0d 0a 63 68 65
63 6b 65 72 3b 32 3b 30 3b 0d 0a

which seems to match with how it looks in txt format.